# Using ESP32CAM board but no face is enrolled

Tags: web-server, esp32-cam

I was working on a project to use the ESP32CAM board to detect faces and open some sort of lock. The program can detect the face using the yellow box that shows up as you can see from the following image:
[image]

But after clicking "Enroll Face", nothing changes. I'm currently using the default CameraWebServer application located in the ESP32CAM board examples. Any advice to solve these issues would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The short version is you need an ESP32-S3 (which the ESP32CAM isn't) if you want practical face recognition from this example. But you *may* be able to make face recognition work on the ESP32CAM with this example *very slowly* if you really want to try it.

---

A comment the example code [explains](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer/CameraWebServer.ino#L9-L11):

> You must select partition scheme from the board menu that has at least 3MB APP space.
> Face **Recognition is DISABLED for ESP32** and ESP32-S2, because it takes up from 15
> seconds to process single frame. Face *Detection* is ENABLED if PSRAM is enabled as well

My understanding is "detection" refers to just what you're seeing in the image you've included, that it can find faces (**any** face) and draw a box around it. This makes sense because [the board has PSRAM](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.14/boards.txt#L16954).

"Recognition" is detection of the **specific** face you "enroll", which "is DISABLED for ESP32". And the ESP32CAM [uses an ESP32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.14/boards.txt#L16947-L16950) (importantly not more powerful ESP32-**S3**)

You can see this again in the form of code rather than a comment [in the web server code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.14/boards.txt#L16947-L16950).

The web page served is not configured to show anything different when those features are disabled. It it just passes events back to the web server code. However, if you're looking at the serial output you should see messages [saying](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.14/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer/app_httpd.cpp#L923C1-L923C48) "Unknown command: face_enroll" and "Unknown command: face_recognize" if you have the Core Debug Level setting at Info level or higher.

---

They say it takes 15 seconds on an plain ESP32, which apparently means it is possible if a bit useless. So, if you really want to try it you may be able to modify [this line](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/2.0.14/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer/app_httpd.cpp#L35C19-L35C19) in app_httpd.cpp to read:

```cpp
#define CONFIG_ESP_FACE_RECOGNITION_ENABLED 1
```

<s>I may try it later if I find my ESP32CAM. But the expectation is that it will "work" but have horrible performance.</s> Well, I found my ESP32CAM and edited that line and yes, it barely functions, but you can see that does technically work, at least for a little while. I may be crashing it during the enroll process or it might just be picking up what it thinks are extra faces and it's so bogged down that it stops responding, which may have motivated why they just disabled it outright. Either way, yeah, it behaves more or less as explained by the comment.